# The encoding in the declaration 'ISO-8859-1' does not match the > encoding of the document 'utf-8'. VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, mantis

When I am trying to send data from vb.net to mc_issue_add I'm getting the following errors :

> An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException' occurred
>   in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

and the inner exception is

> {"The encoding in the declaration 'ISO-8859-1' does not match the
>   encoding of the document 'utf-8'."}

. The pre-defined function is as follows:

```
Function mc_issue_add(ByVal username As String, ByVal password As String, ByVal issue As mantistest.IssueData) As <System.ServiceModel.MessageParameterAttribute(Name:="return"), System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute(DataType:="integer")> String
```

My code :

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim value1 As String
    Dim value2 As String
    Dim value3 As String
    Dim value4 As String

    value1 = Project_Name.SelectedItem.ToString()
    value2 = ComboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()
    value3 = ComboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString()
    value4 = TextBox4.Text

    Dim mantNote As IssueData
    mantNote = New IssueData

    Dim idField As String
    idField = " "

    Dim view_stateField As ObjectRef
    view_stateField = New ObjectRef
    view_stateField.id = 10
    view_stateField.name = " "

    Dim last_updatedField As Date
    last_updatedField = Date.FromOADate(6 / 6 / 2016)

    Dim projectField As ObjectRef
    projectField = New ObjectRef
    projectField.id = 1
    projectField.name = "test"

    Dim categoryField As String
    categoryField = "test"

    Dim priorityField As ObjectRef
    priorityField = New ObjectRef
    priorityField.id = " "
    priorityField.name = "Low"

    Dim severityField As ObjectRef
    severityField = New ObjectRef
    severityField.id = 1
    severityField.name = " "

    Dim statusField As ObjectRef
    statusField = New ObjectRef
    statusField.id = 90
    statusField.name = " "

    Dim reporterField As AccountData
    reporterField = New AccountData
    reporterField.id = " "
    reporterField.name = "Administrator"
    reporterField.real_name = ""
    reporterField.email = ""

    Dim summaryField As String
    summaryField = " "

    Dim versionField As String
    versionField = " "

    Dim buildField As String
    buildField = " "

    Dim platformField As String
    platformField = " "

    Dim osField As String
    osField = " "

    Dim os_buildField As String
    os_buildField = " "

    Dim reproducibilityField As ObjectRef
    reproducibilityField = New ObjectRef
    reproducibilityField.id = 1
    reproducibilityField.name = " "

    Dim date_submittedField As Date
    date_submittedField = Date.FromOADate(6 / 6 / 2016)

    Dim sponsorship_totalField As String
    sponsorship_totalField = " "

    Dim handlerField As AccountData
    handlerField = New AccountData
    handlerField.id = ""
    handlerField.name = "Administrator"
    handlerField.real_name = ""
    handlerField.email = ""

    Dim projectionField As ObjectRef
    projectionField = New ObjectRef
    projectionField.id = " "
    projectField.name = " "

    Dim etaField As ObjectRef
    etaField = New ObjectRef
    etaField.id = " "
    etaField.name = " "

    Dim resolutionField As ObjectRef
    resolutionField = New ObjectRef
    resolutionField.id = " "
    resolutionField.name = "Administrator"

    Dim fixed_in_versionField As String
    fixed_in_versionField = " "

    Dim target_versionField As String
    target_versionField = " "

    Dim descriptionField As String
    descriptionField = " "

    Dim steps_to_reproduceField As String
    steps_to_reproduceField = " "

    Dim additional_informationField As String
    additional_informationField = " "

    Dim s As String = String.Format("Value 1: {0}  value2 : {1} value3: {2} value4: {3}", value1, value2, value3, value4)
    Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(s)

    mantNote.id = idField
    mantNote.view_state = view_stateField
    mantNote.last_updated = last_updatedField
    mantNote.project = projectField
    mantNote.category = categoryField
    mantNote.priority = priorityField
    mantNote.severity = severityField
    mantNote.status = statusField
    mantNote.reporter = reporterField
    mantNote.summary = summaryField
    mantNote.version = versionField
    mantNote.build = buildField
    mantNote.platform = platformField
    mantNote.os = osField
    mantNote.os_build = os_buildField
    mantNote.reproducibility = reproducibilityField
    mantNote.date_submitted = date_submittedField
    mantNote.sponsorship_total = sponsorship_totalField
    mantNote.handler = handlerField
    mantNote.projection = projectionField
    mantNote.eta = etaField
    mantNote.resolution = resolutionField
    mantNote.fixed_in_version = fixed_in_versionField
    mantNote.target_version = target_versionField
    mantNote.description = descriptionField
    mantNote.steps_to_reproduce = steps_to_reproduceField
    mantNote.additional_information = additional_informationField

    TextBox1.Text = QService.mc_issue_add(username:="administrator", password:="root", issue:=mantNote)
End Sub
```

Where have I gone wrong / What mistakes are there in my code? I am pretty new to VB.Net and whatever I have done is with the help of various websites online. Appreciate any help. 
Thanks

Comment: What is the exact error that you get?

Comment: @RobertMunteanu `An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code` and inner exception is `{"The encoding in the declaration 'ISO-8859-1' does not match the encoding of the document 'utf-8'."}`

Comment: It might happen that a error is generated on the server side. Do you have anything in your web server ( Apache,IIS, nginx, etc ) logs?

Comment: @RobertMunteanu No I don't have anything in the logs..

Comment: Then can you try and capture the exact response sent from MantisBT?